# symfony and google identity toolkit

Tags: symfony, google-identity-toolkit

Newbie to PHP and Symfony. Trying to get Symfony to work with google identity toolkit. I followed the steps listed here: https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/quickstart/php

Confused as to where we put the server-side configuration file gitkit-server-config.json [which has the path to the P12 key]

Also, is the path to the key (defined in serviceAccountPrivateKeyFile) an url path or a filesystem path?

Would be great to see if anyone has successfully implemented google identity toolkit with Symfony.

Answer (score 1):

The path to the key is a filesystem path. If you want to dig into how the config file is used, you can check out the open source [client library](https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-php-client).

I'm not particularly familiar with symfony, but you should host the json config file as a private static file.